# How to convert a tree drawn with ete2 to Newick format?

Tags: python, tree, phylogeny, etetoolkit

I have drawn a tree in python using ete2 commands Tree(), .add_child(), .add_sister() and so on.
Is there any way I can convert this tree to the corresponding Newick format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from ete3 import Tree
tree = Tree()
tree.add_child(name="c")
tree.add_child(name="b")
print tree.write()
#(c:1,b:1);
```